# 301 Redirection using htaccess Regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, web-deployment, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect my 301 URLs on some other URls. Below is the cases:

```
xyz.com/html/german = xyz.com/de
xyz.com/german = xyz.com/de
```

one more case :

```
xyz.com/html/german/subpage.html = xyz.com/de/subpage
```

Any one help on this?

I tried with Regex but it is not working:

Here is what I have tried :

```
RewriteRule ^/de/([^/.]+)$ html/german/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your question and shown rule is confusing. What are the URLs you want to show in browser?

Comment: It's pretty simple, I want to redirect my 301 Urls (listed above) to specific page. Please check above examples. Let me explain one of them. :
xyz.com/html/german should be redirect to xyz.com/de
xyz.com/german should be redirect to xyz.com/de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is actually doing reverse. Try these redirect rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(html/)?german/?$ /de

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:html/)?german/([^.]+)(?:\.html)?$ /de/$1
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava,
 It is not working. Issue is now 
http://example.com/html/german/subpage/ is redirecting to this
http://example.com/de/html/german/subpage/ . but it should be like this http://example.com/de/subpage/
Can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: It is still not working bro. is there any possibility that issue with htacces?

Comment: Using this exact rule `http://localhost/html/german/subpage` is getting redirected to `http://localhost/de/subpage` on my Apache. Is that not expected? Make sure these 2 rules are very first rules in your .htaccess

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it on my localhost and it is working but on server where my wordpress is installed, it is not working there. I have added you on hangout, can we chat there?

Comment: This case is not working :
http://localhost/html/niemiecka/subpage.html should be redirect to
http://localhost/de/subpage. Sorry but it is the actual case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash from Rewrite pattern :

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^de/?$ html/german/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^de/([^/.]+)/?$ html/german/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for response. It is only working for below case
xyz.com/html/german = xyz.com/de

For this xyz.com/german, it is taking me on xyz.com/de/german and which is incorrect.

xyz.com/html/german/subpage.html going to below
 xyz.com/de/de/subpage. which is incorrect